# How to change jquery ui dialog width inside the popup dialog itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

In an ASP.Net web page, I created a div and an iFrame to Popup another page in it, what I want to do is channge the dialog width from a button inside the dialog itself...

Is it possible?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to select something outside of iframe from within the iframe, use this:

```
 $("#WhateverIWantOutsideIframe", window.parent.document);
```

So from within iframe, do this

```
$('#InsideButton').on('click',function(){
   $("#DialogOutsideIframe", window.parent.document).width(9000);
});
```

Comment: Even easier. var mydialogbox = $("#DialogOutsideIframe", window.parent.document); //Now do whatever you want with the mydialogbox variable - that IS the dialog box that has been successfully selected. So $(mydialogbox).width(whatever); $(mydialogbox).bind(someotherwhateverevent) , etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dlgContainer = $('#container');

dlgContainer.dialog({
.
.
open : function(){
    dlgContainer.find('#width-change-button').on('click' , function(){ 
        dialogBox.closest('.ui-dialog').css('width', '700px'); //or use .width()
    });
});
```